# How to get failure response for google re-captcha V2. I want to test failure scenario

Tags: model-view-controller, recaptcha

How to get failure response for google re-captcha V2. I want to test failure scenario.
var postData = "secret=" + secretKey + "&response=" + gRecaptchaResponse;
try
{
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlToPost);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

```
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(postData);
            }

            // receive the response now
            string result = string.Empty;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

            // validate the response from Google reCaptcha
            var captchaResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<reCaptchaResponse>(result);

            if (recaptchaLoggingEnabled.ToUpperInvariant() == Constants.True.ToUpperInvariant())
            {
                //Logger.LogAuditData("reCaptcha v2", Convert.ToString(captchaResponse.ErrorCodes), "ValidateRecaptcha", Convert.ToString(captchaResponse), "SSP", Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);
                LogWriter.LogInformation("reCaptcha v2-" + Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name, captchaResponse.Serialize(), Priority.Low, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ToString(), Catogeries.General, "SSP", new KeyValuePair<string, object>("SSP", string.Empty));
            }

            return captchaResponse;
```